# How to be able to understand Cédric Villani's work?

Tags: soft-question, textbook-recommendation

I'm a grad student and I find Villani's work profoundly interesting, though I'm not able to read his papers. My question is, how can i cover the prerequisites to read them?

Comment: Read the introductions of his papers, and see which papers get mentioned as work that his papers build on, and then read those. Repeat this process until you find something that you understand, then build up

Comment: Villani has published close to 100 papers, and different ones will have different prerequisites.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao: Well, this may send you back through a very long chain of papers that all use a common basic idea that you don't understand.  Whereas you might be able to find out about that idea very quickly by reading an appropriate textbook instead, if only someone could tell you what textbook to try.

Comment: @NateEldredge actually, I was looking for something less specific, some textbooks that cover general knowledge of the areas he works in.

Comment: Villani has also written several very nice textbooks/monographs. There are (at least) two about optimal transportation that are quite pedagogical and don't require much background beyond the standard analysis courses, at least to get started.

Comment: As says the last commment there are textbooks and monographs (I'm not a professor) and when you consider what of the subjects in which works Villani is the more nice for you, you can again ask about advice to the previous professors in comments. Also there are lecture notes in YouTube in French and English from several official channels **Institut des Hautes Études Scientifiques (IHÉS)**, also from the official channel **Institut Henri Poincaré**, also from the official channel  **Institute for Advanced Study**.  The search in Google *Landau damping Cédric Villani* returns also information